# HttpServletRequestWrapper - Not able to modify the request header

Tags: java, xss, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

I have a `servlet filter` which is calling `RequestWrapper` class to check and modify the request header.

`public final class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper`

I am overriding `getHeader` method inside `RequestWrapper` class to modify the request header.

```
public String getHeader(String name) {
    String value = super.getHeader(name);
    if (value == null)
      return null;
    return removeUnexpectedCharacters(value);
}

private String removeUnexpectedCharacters(String value)
{
    value = value.replaceAll("script", "");
    value = value.replaceAll("alert", "");
    System.out.println("before return: " + value);
    return value;
}
```

In the server logs, I can see that this code is getting executed and it is actually removing the characters too, however when `response` render to the browser it contains the removed characters too.

When I request a page from server with below URL, it should remove blacklisted characters like `script`, `alert` from `username` parameter.

`https://xxx:8443/ProjectName/login?username=%3E%22%27%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert%2860%29%3C%2Fscript%3E`

Expected URL:

`https://xxx:8443/ProjectName/login?username=%3E%22%27%3E%3C%3E%2860%29%3C%2F%3E`

I am not able to understand what is the issue here. Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Actually most of vulnerability issues are already fix in the application. There are two main issues: 1. Not able to remove blacklisted character from request parameter. 2. Written code to remove blacklisted character from request header is not working as expected.

Comment: @BalusC Can you help me regarding how to remove blacklisted character from request parameter. Suppose I have to do it with existing way. As changing everything will take a long time and I am not in that position. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems to me that you should wrap the Response from the server, not the incoming Request. See this : [HttpServletResponseWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html)
It should be a matter of changing the class your wrapper extends, i.e.
from

```
public final class RequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper
```

to

```
public final class ResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper
```

the implementation shouldn't need to change (but I didn't check that).

Comment: I have updated the question with some more details. Can you please check if your answer still meets the question's requirement?

Comment: I just need to remove blacklisted characters from the request.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you check whether the server code that uses the username parameter receives the cleaned-up value or not?

Comment: It does not do anything with value. The parameterized value will come and sit inside the `HTML DOM` and i do not want this... that's I am removing inside the filter only.

Comment: did you try to add the value back in the header after you edited it? (I don't even know if that's possible, but I see no other reason why it shouldn't work).

Comment: how to do this? I am just overriding `getHeader` method. Nothing else.

Comment: how can I edit the request header and set it back? I am not sure about it.

Comment: From what I see from the javadoc of `HttpSevletRequestWrapper`, there's no apparent way to do it. But, since it is based on a decorator pattern, you could try to override other `getHeader` methods (i.e. `getHeaders` and so on). Maybe the problem is that the servlet is invoking the method you are overriding, but also invokes other methods that return the original value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81510/discussion-between-mike-and-francesco-foresti).